# Django unit test AssertionError: 404 instead 200

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing, view

I'm trying to write a unit test for a view in Django 1.8.
I am trying to test a view that is at an address that contains year and month as parameters.
This is the address to my view:

```
url(r'^/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/(?P<month>[0-9]+)$', views.BookingListView.as_view(), name="list"),
```

Here is my test code:

```
def test_booking_list(self):
    url = reverse('archive:list', kwargs={'year': 2011, 'month': 10})
    response = self.client.get(url)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

I recived an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path to.../test_views.py", line 16, in test_booking_list
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
AssertionError: 404 != 200
```

**EDIT**

Path to view in browser bar: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/archive/2011/01`

View BookingListView:

```
class BookingListView(ListView, MonthArchiveView):
    queryset = models.Booking.objects.order_by('-date_start')
    template_name = 'archive/booking_list.html'
    date_field = 'date_start'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        min_year = self.queryset.aggregate(Min('date_start'))
        max_year = self.queryset.aggregate(Max('date_start'))
        months_choices = []
        for i in range(1, 13):
            months_choices.append({'number': i, 'name': _(calendar.month_name[i])})
        context = super(BookingListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['mode'] = 'archive'
        context['years'] = range(min_year['date_start__min'].year, max_year['date_start__max'].year + 1)
        context['months'] = months_choices
        context['selected_year'] = self.kwargs['year']
        context['selected_month'] = self.kwargs['month']
        context['object_list'] = models.Booking.objects.filter(date_start__year=self.get_year(),
                                                               date_start__month=self.get_month())
        context['current_month_name'] = _(calendar.month_name[int(self.kwargs['month'])])
        return context
```

Comment: What does BookingListView look like? Are there any cases when it raises a 404?

Comment: @DanielRoseman  Please check my edit

Comment: @Kai Have you already created a `BookingList` model with these `year` and `month` ?

Comment: @webcakisa I have the same problem. I definitely create the object in `setUp()`, which is verified by doing `obj = Model.objects.get(attr='value')` and `self.assertEqual(obj.attr, 'value')` right before using `self.client.get` to test the view (which fails the same as in the question).